# Where are the default audio settings located?

Tags: windows-7, audio, troubleshooting, hdmi, default-settings

In the audio devices Control Panel in Windows 7, there's a button titled "Restore Defaults" for any given audio device -- Where are these defaults coming from? Where are they stored (i.e., on-device, in Windows)?

I use an HDMI audio device on my video card. However, no matter what settings I apply to the audio device (i.e., choosing a 7.1 speaker configuration, setting the Default Format to 24bit/48KHz, disabling enhancements), they all get reset to defaults every time I reboot (i.e., 2.1 speaker config, 16bit/44KHz).

I'm trying to locate where these "defaults" are stored so that I can lock them to the settings I need, so they stop getting reset on every reboot, requiring a reconfiguration every time.